# Node js - how to execute two windows commands in sequence and get the output

Tags: node.js

I am trying to execute two windows commands in sequence and get the result of the later one. Something like:

```
cd ${directory}
sfdx force:source:convert -d outputTmp/ --json
```

I have browsed and tried a bunch of third-party libraries, like node-cmd. But so far I haven't got any luck yet. As in node-cmd example:

```
cmd.get(
    `cd ${directory}
    sfdx force:source:convert -d outputTmp/ --json`,
    function(err, data, stderr) {
```

This works very well on my macOS machine. But on Windows it tends to execute only the first command.

Is there anyway I can resolve this issue? Even some walk around for just cd {directory} + real command can be really helpful

Comment: DId you installed all the packages required for the second command on your widows machine (cf: sfdx) ? Does the stderr in the callback return anything ?

Comment: @NathanSchwarz sfdx runs without any issue. In the callback function, the error is null and the data is empty. And if I execute the sfdx command directly, it has no issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;

exec(`cd dir 
      sfdx force:source:convert -d outputTmp/ --json`, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (err) {
    // node couldn't execute the command
    return;
  }
  console.log(stdout);
});
```

or by using `&&` without backticks:

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;

exec('cd dir && sfdx force:source:convert -d outputTmp/ --json', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (err) {
    // node couldn't execute the command
    return;
  }
  console.log(stdout);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for that. Actually a simple && can resolve my issue!